# Manejo de ventana de abrir o guardar fichero tras clicar en link - Python - webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

estoy intentando crear un script python para abrir determinadas urls y clicar en un elemento concreto de la página mostrada. Este elemento una vez clicado devuelve un fichero desde el servidor. Lo que necesito es que este fichero se descargue a una ruta local y lo único que me falta para terminar es manejar la pantalla que windows abre para que el usuario seleccione si desea abrir o guardar el fichero.
[image: Ventana de abrir o guardar archivo]

Por favor, ¿podéis darme alguna pista?
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En principio se me ocurren dos posibilidades:

- Manejar el diálogo automáticamente. Esto no es posible con Selenium, necesitariamos algún framework externo y no siempre es sencillo.
- Lo más simple es evitar que Firefox muestre el diálogo y descargue automáticamente este tipo de archivos dónde queramos modificando la configuraciones del navegador directamente. En el caso de Firefox (que por la imagen usas)

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

  download_folder = "/home/User/Downloads/"

  options = Options()
  options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_folder)
  options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
  options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
  options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/json")
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
  ```

  Estas opciones son las mismas que tenemos [disponibles mediante `about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries) en cualquier navegador Firefox.

  - ***`"browser.download.dir"`***: especifica el directorio por defecto para las descargas.
  - ***`"browser.download.folderList"`***:  una de las siguientes opciones (0, 1, , 2)

    - **0** -> Descarga todos los archivos en el escritorio del usuario
    - **1** -> Descarga en el directorio por defecto de descargas (el definido antes)
    - **2** -> Descarga en el mismo directorio que la descarga anterior.
  - ***`"browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting"`***: especifica si se debe o no mostrar la ventana del administrador de descargas cuando se inicia una.
  - ***`"browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk"`*** especifica mediante una lista separada por comas de [tipos MIME](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) los archivos para los que no va a pedir confirmación para descargarlos en disco.

Dejo un ejemplo reproducible que descarga el instalador para Windows (.zip) de Python desde la web oficial sin mostrar el mencionando diálogo  (para probarlo solo modificar la ruta de descarga):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

download_folder = "/home/User/Downloads/"

options = Options()
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_folder)
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-373/")

download_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".text > table:nth-child(12) > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)")
download_link.click()
```

Comment: Còmo puedo hacer este proceso en Internet Explorer?